# "ruby -v -c 2.0.0p353@myapp" gives "cannot load such file error"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rvm

I have installed `rvm` using [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-14-04-using-rvm) tutorial. Now when I do:
`rvm -version`gives `rvm 1.25.28 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]`

and
`ruby -v` gives `ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux]`

Now, when I am trying this command: `ruby -v -c 2.0.0p353@myapp`
  it is giving error-`ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux]
ruby: No such file or directory -- 2.0.0p353@myapp (LoadError)`

Comment: Why do you use `-c` argument? What for?

Comment: c = create and v = version

Comment: Run `ruby -h` and you'll see `-c check syntax only`.

Comment: ohh...what's the correct command to create myapp.

Comment: Well, I bet you should RTFM. Start from here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running  below command worked for me.

`rvm --ruby-version --create 2.0.0@myapp`. 
On running this command for few users, it might ask to install few things, example in my case:
`ruby-2.0.0-p481 is not installed.`
`To install do: 'rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p481`

Run this command and try again, it would work.